# ASP.NET Core in IIS, (ICollection/List/Array) appsettings.json -> web.config

Tags: json, iis, asp.net-core, web-config, appsettings

Using the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2) I created a class with an `ICollection<string> allowedHosts` property. Inside the `appsettings.json` I've added `[ "google.nl", "bing.com" ]` and when the app is running in Development mode everything is fine.

However, in production, we use IIS and by using the Configuration Editor of IIS to define the `environmentVariables`, and this gets saved as `web.config` and will somewhat look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <aspNetCore>
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
                <environmentVariable name="AllowedHosts" value="How to format?" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My problem is: how can I convert this JSON from the `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "allowedHosts": [ "google.com", "bing.com" ]
}
```

To XML for the `web.config` file? I tried using `["google.com"]`, `"google.com"` but none is working.

Edit: I've used a bad property name, in this case the `AllowedHosts` has a different use and I should change the property name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AllowedHosts` is a special configuration that accepts a semicolon-delimited list of host names without port numbers.
For more details, see [Host filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#host-filtering) .

If you need allow multiple hosts, you could configure it as below :

```xml
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\abc.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="AllowedHosts" value="google.com;bing.com" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

---

If you would like to get array from `Web.Config` configuration, you could change the key name to be :

```
<key-name>:<index>
```

e.g. :

```xml
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="AllowedHosts:0" value="google.com" />
    <environmentVariable name="AllowedHosts:1" value="bing.com" />
</environmentVariables>
```

To get the array in ASP.NET Core :

```
var allowed =  _config.GetSection("AllowedHosts").AsEnumerable();

/* output :
[  
   {  
      "key":"AllowedHosts",
      "value":"*"
   },
   {  
      "key":"AllowedHosts:1",
      "value":"bing.com"
   },
   {  
      "key":"AllowedHosts:0",
      "value":"google.com"
   }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you set that up in your Startup class?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2